# What does it mean to Taylor expand $1/(\ln(r) - \ln(x) + i\pi/2)$ in power of $1/\ln(x)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion, complex-integration

**What does it mean to Taylor expand $1/(\ln(r)-\ln(x)+i\pi/2)$ in power of $1/\ln(x)$?**

[image]

Can some one help me understand what this text means? I could understand everything except for the last step which is to Taylor expand that part of the integrand in power of $1/\ln(x)$. I tried regularly Taylor expand it, but I encounter product rules and it does not seem to be the same as what is in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an expression
$$
\frac{1}{a-w}.
$$
You can expand it as a geometric series in $\frac aw$ with the understanding that $|w|>|a|$ using the identity
$$
\frac{1}{a-w}=-\frac1w\cdot\frac1{1-\frac aw}=-\frac1w⋅\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\frac aw\right)^k.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. Lol, it is so simple. The text said taylor seires, but is geometric series a type of Taylor expanding?   I guess I have to go over the definition.